# Binding spring boot application properties to java.util.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I am creating a spring-boot application which also creates bean for one of the classes of an external lib, this external java bean needs java.util.properties as one of the constructor parameter. Although I can use configurationPropeties with prefix to read properties from the spring boot loaded property file and convert it to java.util.properties.However, I don't want any additional prefix in the property file. is there any other way where I can convert the spring-boot loaded env or property source to java.util.properties

here is the code for reference

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "some.prefix")
    @Bean
    public Properties getProperties() {
        return new Properties();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExternalClass externalClass() throws ConfigException {
        return ExternalClass.getInstance(getProperties());
    }
}
```

the above code work nicely, but I need to add an unnecessary prefix to the properties for conversion. could someone suggest any other approach apart from adding prefix to the propeties

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/28/property-binding-in-spring-boot-2-0) documentation. It explains property binding techniques used in spring-boot.

Comment: I have already used binding in one way. if you have any other way then please explain..